My youtube video is not showing in html for free crypto signal
This is my code:
<h3>This is how paid version works!</h3>

<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://youtu.be/vkzenqf-uHE?si=folEd8izGsUSKNou">
</iframe>

This the live webpage:
https://englishact.com/free.php
Could you help me to correct the code?

You're using the short URL for the YT video. Use the embed URL instead. <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vkzenqf-uHE?si=UdsO45ALCJGPnu43" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>

And for GDPR reasons use the https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed instead of https://www.youtube.com/embed

how to get embed url?

@AsifIqbal either use the iframe in my comment or when on the YT video page, click share, then pick the first option (white icon with the <> symbols).

There are two ways:

If you add with iframe that's also good.
If you add like this then this also works:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkzenqf-uHE
Or you can use embed in the place of watch:  https://www.youtube.com/embed/vkzenqf-uHE


The embed option always needs an iframe (so be aware that it's the same thing as step 1).
